# How to filter list by dates angular 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, ngfor, angular-pipe

I am developing one tool in angular 6 where each logged in user has some assigned tasks. currently, I am getting all the tasks in one array. I have done some manipulation at client side like adding start & end time  & store all on local storage. I want to filter the tasks by dates means today's tasks displays in today's list tomorrows tasks displays in tomorrows list & same for all week.[image: all tasks]

```js
// response
[{
 "id": "5c9a108aab16141aca472980",
 "idBoard": "5c7cf3d22c86ae1f9a210571",
 "idList": "5c7cf40cb8f22b26862602aa",
 "name": "Newest Card 1",
 "due": "2019-03-27T06:30:00.000Z",
  "time": "2019-03-25T18:30:12.000Z"
}, 
{
 "id": "5c9a108aab16141aca472950",
 "idBoard": "5c7cf3d22c86ae1f9a210571",
 "idList": "5c7cf40cb8f22b26862602aa",
 "name": "Newest Card 2",
 "due": "2019-03-27T06:30:00.000Z"
},
 {
 "id": "5c9a108aab16141aca472960",
 "idBoard": "5c7cf3d22c86ae1f9a210571",
 "idList": "5c7cf40cb8f22b26862602aa",
 "name": "Newest Card 3",
 "due": "2019-03-27T06:30:00.000Z"
},
 {
 "id": "5c9a108aab16141aca472970",
 "idBoard": "5c7cf3d22c86ae1f9a210571",
 "idList": "5c7cf40cb8f22b26862602aa",
 "name": "Newest Card 4",
 "due": "2019-03-27T06:30:00.000Z",
   "time": "2019-03-25T18:30:50.000Z"

}
]
```

```html
<div class="card width hr" *ngFor="let item of allUserTaskArr;let i = index">
      <div class="card-header">
        <span class="due" [ngClass]="{'text-orange': (item.due | date) == (today | date), 'text-red': (item.due | date) < (today | date), 'text-default': (item.due | date) > (today | date)}" ><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp; {{item.due | date}}</span>
        <span class="float-right font-weight-bold pad-top-05" [class.due-time] = "(item.time | date:'HH:mm:ss') != undefined" [class.text-default] = "(item.time | date:'HH:mm:ss') != undefined" *ngIf="(item.time | date:'HH:mm:ss') != '00:00:00'">
          <i class="fa fa-clock-o" *ngIf="(item.time | date:'HH:mm:ss') != undefined"></i>&nbsp; {{item.time | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}
        </span>
        <a class="link mar-l-r-1 float-right pad-top-05" ><i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Create Checklist</a>
        <a class="link mar-l-r-1 float-right pad-top-05" *ngIf="item.timeEntries != undefined" (click)="hideme[i] = !hideme[i]"><i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o"></i>&nbsp; Time Entries</a>

      </div>
      <div class="card-body pad-125">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <span *ngIf="role === 'tl' || role === 'tm'">
              <input type="checkbox" class="" (change)="finsishTask(item)">
            </span>&nbsp; 
            <h6 class="display-inline-block pad-t-075 mar-btm-05">{{item.name}}</h6>
         
            <div class="float-right">
              <button class="btn btn-info mar-l-r-0-5 box-shadow" *ngIf="item.start" (click)="startTask(item);setStartTime(item)"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>&nbsp; Start</button>
              <button class="btn btn-danger mar-l-r-0-5 box-shadow" *ngIf="item.end" (click)="EndTask(item);setEndTime(item)"><i class="fa fa-stop-circle"></i>&nbsp; End</button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="hideme[i]"  [@enterAnimation]>
            <hr class="hr"> 
            <h6 class="mar-btm-05">Time Entries</h6>
            <div class="row no-gutters">
              <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let time of item.timeEntries">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp; 
                <span *ngIf="time.startTime != 'null'">{{time.startTime | date: 'dd/MM, (h:mm a)'}}</span>&nbsp; -&nbsp;
                <span *ngIf="time.endTime != 'null'">{{time.endTime | date: 'dd/MM, (h:mm a)'}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

In the above code, I am getting this kind of response I want to filter the tasks at the client side on due date.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you meant to say you want to sort by due date. Is that so?

Comment: actually, I want to do something like this https://teuxdeux.com/

Comment: but if I want to sort the tasks on due date in ngFor how can I do?

Comment: create a pipe filter  for the same

Answer (score 0):

You just have to sort the **allUserTaskArr** by due dates with a sort function.

```
allUserTaskArr.sort((a,b)=>a.due - b.due);
```

teuxdeux.com also finds the categorizes all tasks according to the due date. For that you need to reduce the array into an object with due date as the key and the tasks as its value.

Then it shows you the nearest date first.

You will have to modify your html as well to accommodate this structure.

Answer (score 0):

it is actually quite simple. Let me modify your sample data by a bit such that the last element in `arr` is of a different date.

```
const arr = [{
    "id": "5c9a108aab16141aca472980",
    "idBoard": "5c7cf3d22c86ae1f9a210571",
    "idList": "5c7cf40cb8f22b26862602aa",
    "name": "Newest Card 1",
    "due": "2019-03-27T06:30:00.000Z",
  "time": "2019-03-25T18:30:12.000Z"
}, 
{
    "id": "5c9a108aab16141aca472950",
    "idBoard": "5c7cf3d22c86ae1f9a210571",
    "idList": "5c7cf40cb8f22b26862602aa",
    "name": "Newest Card 2",
    "due": "2019-03-27T06:30:00.000Z"
},
 {
    "id": "5c9a108aab16141aca472960",
    "idBoard": "5c7cf3d22c86ae1f9a210571",
    "idList": "5c7cf40cb8f22b26862602aa",
    "name": "Newest Card 3",
    "due": "2019-03-27T06:30:00.000Z"
},
 {
    "id": "5c9a108aab16141aca472970",
    "idBoard": "5c7cf3d22c86ae1f9a210571",
    "idList": "5c7cf40cb8f22b26862602aa",
    "name": "Newest Card 4",
    "due": "2019-03-28T06:30:00.000Z",
   "time": "2019-03-25T18:30:50.000Z"

}
]
```

Here is how we can sort your array:

```
const sortedArr = [...arr].sort((a,b)=> a.due - b.due);
```

If you would like to filter the data such that only tasks due today are returned,

```
const today = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
const filterToday = arr.filter(obj => new Date(obj['due']).setHours(0,0,0,0) === today);

console.log(filterToday);
```

We set the hours to (0,0,0,0) so that only the date/month/year will be factored in the filter function.

Likewise, if you would like to get tasks that are due tomorrow,

```
const tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1);

const filterTomorrow = arr.filter(obj => new Date(obj['due']).setHours(0,0,0,0) === tomorrow.setHours(0,0,0,0));

console.log(filterTomorrow);
```